# How to fix 'incompatible dimensions' error from cor() function

Tags: r, r-caret, rpart

I am using the predict() function to predict the Purchase variable in blackFriday_test. When I use cor() with theses variables as arguments, I get an 'incompatible dimensions' error message.

I tried looking at the dimension of the Purchas variable in blackFriday_test which is 107516, but the predicted values turn out to be only 32955.

The data was downloaded from https://www.kaggle.com/mehdidag/black-friday.

```
library(caret)

blackFriday <- read.csv("BlackFriday.csv", stringsAsFactors = T)
```

## Here I remove the first two features because they are identifiers

```
nblackFriday <- blackFriday[, 3:12]
```

```
set.seed(189)
train <- sample(nrow(nblackFriday), as.integer(0.8 * nrow(nblackFriday)), replace = F)

blackFriday_train <- nblackFriday[train, ]
blackFriday_test <- nblackFriday[-train, ]
```

## Removing NA's from the two variables where they are present

````
nblackFriday$Product_Category_2 <- ifelse(is.na(nblackFriday$Product_Category_2), mean(nblackFriday$Product_Category_2, na.rm = T), nblackFriday$Product_Category_2)
nblackFriday$Product_Category_3 <- ifelse(is.na(nblackFriday$Product_Category_3), mean(nblackFriday$Product_Category_3, na.rm = T), nblackFriday$Product_Category_3)

blackFriday_train$Product_Category_2 <- nblackFriday$Product_Category_2[train]
blackFriday_train$Product_Category_3 <- nblackFriday$Product_Category_3[train]

m <- train(Purchase ~ ., data = blackFriday_train, method = "rpart")

p <- predict(m, blackFriday_test)

cor(p, blackFriday_test$Purchase)
```
#This is where I get the error

I expect the number of predicted values to be the same as the number of rows in blackFriday_test, but they are not.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You replaced NAs in your training set, but *not* in your testing set, so those cases are being omitted.

```
> head(blackFriday_test)
   Gender   Age Occupation City_Category Stay_In_Current_City_Years Marital_Status Product_Category_1
3       F  0-17         10             A                          2              0                 12
6       M 26-35         15             A                          3              0                  1
15      F 51-55          9             A                          1              0                  5
16      F 51-55          9             A                          1              0                  4
21      M 26-35         12             C                         4+              1                  5
22      M 26-35         12             C                         4+              1                  8
   Product_Category_2 Product_Category_3 Purchase
3                  NA                 NA     1422
6                   2                 NA    15227
15                  8                 14     5378
16                  5                 NA     2079
21                 14                 NA     8584
22                 NA                 NA     9872
```

Just impute them like you did for the training set it works as expected.

```
blackFriday_test$Product_Category_2 <- nblackFriday$Product_Category_2[-train]
blackFriday_test$Product_Category_3 <- nblackFriday$Product_Category_3[-train]
p <- predict(m, blackFriday_test)
```

```
> length(p) == nrow(blackFriday_test)
[1] TRUE
> cor(p, blackFriday_test$Purchase)
[1] 0.7405558
```

Try using the partitioning and preprocessing features of caret, itself. For me they help to avoid these types of easy errors.

Answer (score 0):

You replaced missing values in the train dataset, but not on the test one. So your prediction on the test is lower than the number of rows of your test dataset.

You should apply your operations (like replacing NA's) on the full dataset, and split in train/test after. This way, your both datasets will be similar, and prediction will better work.